# The scale anomaly and dependence on scale

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-anomalies, scale-invariance

The scale anomaly states that if we have renormalizable theory without dimensionful function, which is scale invariant, then corresponding quantum theory may lost this symmetry because of regularization. Corresponding current, called dilatation current, isn't conserved:
$$
\tag 1 \partial_{\mu}\langle |\theta^{\mu}|\rangle = F[\beta (\mu), \mu],
$$
where $F[...]$ is called scale anomaly function.
For example, in QCD
$$
 \partial_{\mu}\langle |\theta^{\mu}|\rangle \sim \frac{\beta (g)}{g_{s}}G_{\mu \nu}^{a}G^{\mu \nu}_{a}
$$
The question: does dependence of $F$ on the fictious scale $\mu$ imply that the scale anomaly equation $(1)$ is scale dependent? Or, when we talk about the scale dependence of anomaly equation, we mean the principal existence of anomaly function $F$ in the rhs of Eq.$(1)$?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. What do you mean by "scale dependence of anomaly equation"? Anyways, for classically scale-independent theories (with dimensionless couplings) like QED or QCD, the dependence of the beta-function on $\mu$ is only implicit through $\beta(g(\mu))$.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus : But the beta-function depends on the scale $\mu$, which in principle means that near the critical point the scale invariance is restored. By writing "the scale invariance" of the scale anomaly I compare the scale anomaly with chiral anomaly, which is scale invariant due to topological reasoning.